# How to properly wait until function has finished doing in swift?

Tags: swift, closures, completionhandler

I have now tried lots of things, but none of them seem to work.

I have a for loop which parses some data and converts coordinates into ZIP string:

```
for i in 0 ... results.count - 1
{
    result = results[i]
    self.coordinateToString(lat: result.lat, long: result.long, completion: { (place) in
                        someCell.label.text = place
                    })
}

func coordinateToString(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    var ret = ""

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
    {
        placemarks, error -> Void in

        guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

        if let zip = placeMark.postalCode, let town = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea
        {
            let toAppend = "\(zip)" + " \(town)"
            ret = toAppend

        }
    })

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(ret)
    }
}
```

However I never manage to show the correct place in the cell, it always shows empty space because it somehow doesn't wait for the completion handler to finish converting. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have the call to `DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(ret) }` in the wrong place.

Comment: wow please read some swift conventions of how to code, this is unreadable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `reverseGeocodeLocation` returns right away and its completion handler runs afterwards.  This means that `ret` value may be empty when it gets put on the main queue.  You should dispatch to main from within the callback, like so:

```
func coordinateToString(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
  let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
  let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
  var ret = ""

  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
  {
    placemarks, error -> Void in

    guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

    if let zip = placeMark.postalCode, let town = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea
    {
        let toAppend = "\(zip)" + " \(town)"
        ret = toAppend
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(ret)
       }
    }
})
```

Of course, given this scenario, you need to handle error cases accordingly.  Better yet, use `defer`, that way completion gets called regardless of what happens:

```
func coordinateToString(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
  let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
  let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
  var ret = ""

  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
  {
    defer {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          completion(ret)
       }
    } 

    placemarks, error -> Void in

    guard let placeMark = placemarks?.first else { return }

    if let zip = placeMark.postalCode, let town = placeMark.subAdministrativeArea
    {
        let toAppend = "\(zip)" + " \(town)"
        ret = toAppend
    }
})
```